PowerBi - creating complex matrix with subcategories, counts and totals
I'd like to create a PowerBI Matrix which looks like this in Excel:


Pass, Fail is counted as number of Pass/Faill occurrences in the Result Column
Status is pass if all pass, fail if 1 fails, unsupp if neither was executed
Total Passed, Total Failed is self explanatory

The best I can do, using subcategories is something like this:

The problem is that although I can create categories in Rows (ID at the top, Name below) and Columns (Groups at the top, Result below) with values using count, I can't add Status column or specific counters.
Is it possible to complete this task using power BI and one matrix?
